# How do I reflash both partitions of a Google Pixel 6 Pro device in one go?

Tags: adb, rom-flashing, google-pixel, google-pixel-6

How do I reflash both partitions of a Google Pixel 6 Pro device in one go?

If I follow the instructions at https://developers.google.com/android/images, I have to:

1. reflash the first, default partition (a or b) using flash-all.bat
2. return to the bootloader (which means either (A) turning the device off after it automatically reboots and booting back into the bootloader using the hardware buttons or (B) doing a "false setup" of the device (after it automatically reboots) and returning to the bootloader via Android's Developer Options screen and the `adb reboot bootloader` command
3. set the inactive partition to the active partition using `fastboot set_active a` or `fastboot set_active b`
4. reflash the second, remaining partition using flash-all.bat

Is there a way to combine these reflashing steps to make reflashing both partitions less troublesome?

(Note: My goal with reflashing both partitions instead of one is to eliminate malware, so simply nuking and regenerating both partitions from scratch would also be a workable solution, but I don't know how to do that either.)

Comment: I do remember that when I flashed devices some time ago the new image also don't?aimed a new bootloader and the flash script automatically performed a reboot after flashing the bootloader to load the new bootloader. After reboot directly fastboot mode was active again, so there should be a command to reboot the device directly from within fastboot so that after reboot you again end up in fastboot mode so you don't have to fiddle with hardware buttons or boot the device to be able to use adb.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make a minimalistic effort and don't have much experience to modify your flash-all.bat script, just do this.

1. Run flash-all.bat on your existing boot slot.
2. Reboot the phone to fastboot on other slot:

   `fastboot set_active other` (sets the currently inactive slot as active i.e. a => b or b => a)

   `fastboot reboot-bootloader` (reboots the phone to bootloader/fastboot. If this does not work, then try `fastboot reboot bootloader`)
3. Rerun flash-all.bat; This time, it will flash your other slot.

Alternatively, depending on your experience and skill, you can embed the slot change and reboot-bootloader into the flash all script and then call the flash commands again. However, I think that the above steps will do the work without you needing time and effort to modify the flash sequence.